# PHP set warnings as fatal

Tags: php, apache, configuration

Is there a way to specify in php.ini or apache level that the script execution should halt on any warnings? I tried searching through google and stackoverflow but couldn't find any relevant information yet. I do know about the set_error_handler() function but I am looking to do this at the php.ini level.

Comment: why do you want such odd behavior?

Comment: i dont want it, i want to make sure it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like always it's a little difficult to prove a negative like you're asking.  About 14 seconds of googling yields the complete list of php.ini directives:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

There are only 4 instances of the word 'warning' on this page, so it looks like that exotic idea is not an option.

Comment: while i do not agree to the method of your search (halting can well be under a more general category and not with the word 'warning'), i do agree that this is an exotic idea :-).. just wanted to make sure that the warning messages on a production server could never affect my script execution... thanks.

Comment: I suppose you're right and if I was launching a space shuttle I would have put a little more effort into making sure there did not exist other directives that perhaps caused this behavior when toggled and were disguised as something innocent. :-)

Just wanted to suggest to you the place I would look and give an example of how I would look for it.  Like I said, difficult to prove the negative without testing or looking at code.  

You could also grep php.ini because, especially in 5.3 there are a ton of comments and if what you're looking for exists its comment might contain warning or hault.

Comment: This isn't an answer about how to make Warnings stop the interpreter.  I think the correct answer is that it is a limitation of PHP. There is no configuration option to stop the interpreter on all errors. An example is "Too few arguments" in vsprintf. It is a warning, so it will not stop the interpreter unless you create a custom error handler.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT Sep 2021:** OP does not want this solved by using a custom error function like I propose, but this question gets quite some traffic by people who are perfectly happy using a custom error function.

```php
// Custom error function (even triggers for warnings)
set_error_handler(function($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
    if(error_reporting() & $severity) {
        throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
   }
});
```

In the project I am using this code in, I made this little helper function to switch at different parts of the project. Possible values are 0, 1 and 2

```php
function updateErrorHandling($state) {
    //custom error handler or standard
    if($state > 1) {
        // Custom error function (even triggers for warnings)
        set_error_handler(function($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
            if(error_reporting() & $severity) {
                throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    // Standard Exception Handling on / off
    ini_set('display_errors', $state);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', $state);
    error_reporting($state == 1 ? E_ALL : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to do something like that at the configuration level.  However, I think it could be done using PHP's `set_error_handler` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Within the function you set, can detect a warning via the `ERROR_TYPE` parameter, and halt the script using `exit` or `die`.

Comment: please read the question properly. i have already added that I know about the set_error_handler function but need a setting on the php.ini level. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Please read the answer, and the other answer: There is no way to do what you are asking for.  The answer attempted to provide the behaviour you're looking for, if not by the means you wanted.

Comment: @ChrisHenry - did you mean "AFAIK"?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [xdebug.halt_level](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#halt_level)